# Working with -filter_complex in ffmpeg with a batch concat array

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, cmd, concatenation, batch-processing

What I am trying to do here is write an ffmpeg script that takes all songs from a folder and combines them into one audio file using the command line in Windows.

So far I have

```
ffmpeg -i "pathforinput1" -i "pathforinput2" -i "pathforinputn" -filter_complex "[0:0] [1:0] concat=n=(number of songs goes here):v=0:a=1 "[a]"" -map "[a]" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "output file.mp3"
```

My problem is that I want to combine it with the existing script:

`for %A in ("input folder\*.extension") do ffmpeg`

to create a total script that uses `-i "%A"` for the input. The problem I am having here is that each input file requires an entry in the array `-filter_complex "[0:0] [1:0]` as well as having the total number of input files present in `concat=n=(number of files)`. I' m willing to use a batch script to make this possible, but I can't see how I would go about finding the total number of files in a folder and then creating an array for each (for example if there were 7 songs the array would be `[0:0] [1:0] [2:0] [3:0] [4:0] [5:0] [6:0]`).

Any help or pointers for making this possible would be great. Someone in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176295/ffmpeg-concat-batch-loop-with-text-file) question managed to make something similar for a Unix system but I am using batch files and I don't know how to modify it for Windows.

Thanks in advance for any help

Ok, progress made with the help of the first commenter. However, I think ffmpeg isn't liking what I've made. My code thus far is:

```
:: Give you a list of the .wav filenames in -i "filename1" -i "filename2" format

for %%a in ("C:\Users\James\Input\*.*") do call set var=%%var%% -i "%%a"
echo %var%

:: Give you the number of .mp3 files

for /f %%a in ('dir "C:\Users\James\Input\*.*" /b /a-d ^|find /c /v "" ') do set "numfiles=%%a"
echo there are "%numfiles%" files
set /a totalnum=numfiles

:: dir "C:\Users\James\Input\" /b >> C:\Users\James\Output\filelist.txt
:: print some text
set /a numfiles=numfiles-1
for /L %%b in (0,1,%numfiles%) do call set array=%%array%% [%%b:0]
:: for /L %%b in (0,1,%numfiles%) do call set array=%%array%% [0:0]
echo %array%
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%C in ('echo %array% ') do set array=%%C
set array=%array:~0,-1%
echo %array%
:: for %%d in ("C:\Users\James\Input\*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%d" -filter_complex "%array% concat=n=%totalnum%:v=0:a=1 "[a]"" -map "[a]" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "C:\Users\James\Output\outputtestbatch1.mp3"
for %%d in ("C:\Users\James\Input\*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%d" -filter_complex "%array% concat=n=%totalnum%:v=0:a=1 "[a]"" -map "[a]" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "C:\Users\James\Output\outputtestbatch1.mp3"
pause`
```

The issue I am having now is that I think ffmpeg is assuming each input file has audio stream [0:0] rather than incrementing them one after the other. Is there a way to fix this with the input method I'm using?

**SECOND EDIT**L: Success! I modified foxidrive's script a bit because it was slightly misconfigured. Final product is here:

```
@echo off

for %%a in ("C:\Users\James\Input\*.*") do call set var=%%var%% -i "%%a"
:: echo %var%
:: Give you the number of files

for /f %%a in ('dir "C:\Users\James\Input\*.*" /b /a-d ^|find /c /v "" ') do set "numfiles=%%a"
echo there are "%numfiles%" files

for /L %%b in (0,%numfiles%) do call set array=%%array%% [%%b:0]
set array=%array:~1%
echo "%array%"

ffmpeg %var% -filter_complex "%array% concat=n=%numfiles%:v=0:a=1 "[a]"" -map "[a]" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "C:\Users\James\Output\outputtestbatch1.mp3"

popd    
pause
```

Comment: Is the change in the `For /L` command?  Your change there makes the syntax wrong.

Comment: consider using a scripting language to do it too :)

Comment: @foxidrive Yep, it was generating n + 1 results in the array rather than n results, I just removed the ,1 in `for /L %%b in (0,%numfiles%)` and it works fine now.

Comment: It only gives one result now `[0:0]` and that's all.  On the line above the `for /L` add this line `set /a numfiles-=1` and also put the `,1` back.  I removed the line that takes one off the variable during the several edits and didn't realise.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** added a series of filetypes: *.WAV *.MP3 *.FLAC *.M4A

These three snippets will:

```
:: Give you a list of the filenames in -i "filename1" -i "filename2" format

for %%a in (*.WAV *.MP3 *.FLAC *.M4A) do call set var=%%var%% -i "%%a"
echo %var%

:: Give you the number of .wav files

for /f %%a in ('dir *.WAV *.MP3 *.FLAC *.M4A /b /a-d ^|find /c /v "" ') do set "numfiles=%%a"
echo there are "%numfiles%" files

:: print some text
set /a numfiles=numfiles-1
for /L %%b in (0,1,%numfiles%) do call set array=%%array%% [%%b:0]
echo %array%
pause
```

**Note:** that there is an 8 KB command length limit in many aspects of cmd.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, thanks! I was wondering, is there any way to include more than one filetype? I'll be using WAV, MP3, FLAC and M4A files. would `for %%a in (*.*) do call set var=%%var%% -i "%%a"` work if there are only the audio files that I need in the directory and nothing else?

Comment: See my edit above, the set of filespecs can simply be added.  Using `*.*` will include the batch file name too, but that could be worked around.  Note that if you have stacks of files then you might run out of space on the command line.

Comment: Please check my question edit, more ffmeg issues have arisen! Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Using `*.*` is going to include the batch file name.

Comment: The batch is in another place and I am using the full path to the input folder that just contains stuff I need combining.

Comment: Exactly what I need too, but for Mac. Could anybody translate this for MacOS Terminal please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see what happens.  Try it with two files only in the folder to begin with.

```
@echo off

pushd "C:\Users\James\Input\"

for %%a in ("*.*") do call set var=%%var%% -i "%%a"
:: echo %var%
:: Give you the number of files

for /f %%a in ('dir "*.*" /b /a-d ^|find /c /v "" ') do set "numfiles=%%a"
echo there are "%numfiles%" files

:: dir "C:\Users\James\Input\" /b >> C:\Users\James\Output\filelist.txt

for /L %%b in (0,1,%numfiles%) do call set array=%%array%% [%%b:0]
:: echo %array%
set array=%array:~1%
echo "%array%"

ffmpeg %var% -filter_complex "%array% concat=n=%totalnum%:v=0:a=1 "[a]"" -map "[a]" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "C:\Users\James\Output\outputtestbatch1.mp3"

popd    
pause
```

Comment: Make sure your quoting is ok too because it looks odd.  The `-i` is not needed as every filename has a `-i` according to the rules you posted.

Comment: Whoops, sorted it! Check my final edit for the finished code. Thanks so much for all your help!